# I want my software to respond when someone inserts a coin, how can I do it?

Tags: hardware, usb, hardware-interface

I understand this can seem a bit weird. So I'll give more details.

Is it possible for my computer to interact with some kind of "coin collector" ( just like the kind that's used in a vending machine ) ?

Basically I'd like to be able to implement the following methods

```
public void onCoinInserted( Coin coin ){
    if( coin.value == 10 )
        unlockGame();...
```

Is there some USB hardware I could plug to my PC that can do this? Any help would be appreciated, it's very hard to find those devices.

Comment: No idea whether it's any good, but Googling turns up this: http://www.coinopexpress.com/products/parts/cash_handling/USB_Coin_Acceptor_%284_coins_4_signals%29_7036.html

Comment: and more on Google: http://www.google.com/#hl=de&safe=off&q=USB+Coin+acceptor&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=5ab3615e37143015 won't beat a personal recommendation but still.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of very simple to use microcontroller boards.

The Arduino boards are all the rage right now and are well supported under different OS'es and development platforms